# Objective-C detect DNS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dns

Does anyone knows how can i detect from an app the DNS of the iPhone?

**UPDATE:** If there're different ways of obtaining the DNS server and DNS host name, any solution is acceptable.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the DNS"_?  The DNS host name of the iPhone? The DNS server that the iPhone is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the host name you can use libc API, gethostname:

```
#import <unistd.h>

...

char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX];
int err = gethostname(hostname, HOST_NAME_MAX);
if(!err)
    NSLog(@"My hostname is %s", hostname);
```

Comment: Well, that's not the best option.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, and possibly better way, to do this, is to use the Core Foundations APIs.

More specifically, the `CFHost` API will do asynchronous host resolution.

You can ask a `CFHost` instance to start resolving a host and test for its reachability. The process will happen on a runloop and you will get callbacks when the resolution has finished.

It is a good alternative for the blocking `gethostname` call.

Comment: Some actual code on how to actually use CFHost to get the local host name would be useful.